# How do I multithread my Scala server?

Tags: scala, sockets, concurrency, server

I've been programming a simple client/server application that sends one response back in Scala, and I've been trying to multithread my server using `ExecutionContext` without any luck.

This is my server code, I think the position of my execute block is causing errors:

```
import java.net._;
import java.io._;
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext

object ServerTwo extends App {
  var s1: Socket = null; 
  var dis: DataInputStream = null;
  var s1In: InputStream= null;
  var o1out: OutputStream = null;
  var odos: DataOutputStream = null

  while(true){

    def execute(body: =>Unit)=
         ExecutionContext.global.execute( new Runnable {def run()= body}) 

    try{

      // Open your connection to a server, at port 1234
      var s: ServerSocket = new ServerSocket(999)
      s1 = s.accept(); // Wait and accept a connection

      execute{
        s1In = s1.getInputStream()
        dis = new DataInputStream(s1In)
        var st = new String (dis.readUTF())
        //println("Word received is "+st )     
        st="Received message";

        var o1out: OutputStream = null; var odos: DataOutputStream = null
        o1out = s1.getOutputStream()
        odos = new DataOutputStream (o1out)
        // Send the string back
        odos.writeUTF(st);

      }//end execute
    }//end try

    catch {
      case e: Exception => 
    } finally {
      // Close the connection, but not the server socket
      try{
        s1.close()
      }
      catch{
        case e: Exception =>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please point out the exact problem (the error)? How can it be reproduced?

Comment: If this is for an assignment, then look up how to multithread in Scala (hint: It's basically the same as Java - start at https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html).  If you're trying to make a real application, don't reinvent the wheel.  There are many good server frameworks out there that will handle multithreading for you; find one that meets your use case and use it.